# Branch.io (Android SDK) and GDPR

Tags: java, android, branch.io, fabric.io, attribution

I want my app to be GDPR compliant. It means that I want to avoid to launch any tool like Branch.io as long as the user did not give its consent.

My problem is that the Branch.io documentation https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/  mentions that I have to put the following code in my launcher activity :

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Branch init
        Branch.getInstance().initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    Log.i("BRANCH SDK", referringParams.toString());
                } else {
                    Log.i("BRANCH SDK", error.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        this.setIntent(intent);
    }
```

It is also mentioned in the doc :

> Only initialize Branch in the Launcher activity
>
> The app will open through the Launcher activity, where Branch will initialize and retrieve the deep link data from the link click.

So, I don't see how to make something GDPR compliant. Indeed, if this code really needs to be executed in the onStart of the launcher activity, I don't have time to execute it before the user gave its consent.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Why did you open a second question with the same purpose?

Comment: Because my first question was not asked in the same way ; and perhaps not clear enough !

Comment: You can edit your existing question.

Comment: I think that it will be too long. I think that is better with 2 questions with different contents/explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same documentation, there is an explanation about how to disable tracking by Branch SDK, so your application is GDPR compliant, but still keep all the SDK features. 
[Here's the anchor to that section](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#enable-disable-user-tracking).

All you need to do is implement the following code right before calling the `initSession()`:

`Branch.getInstance().disableTracking(true);`

You will need to build out the handling of this line based on whether the user gave a consent for tracking or not.